# why the appended row's data didn't displayed after being submitted?

Tags: php, javascript

this is my php code(1st page):

```
        <table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_1" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_2" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><textarea name="pro_3" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
            </tr>
            <input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD">
```

incorporated with javascript for append the row when button is clicked:

```
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=parseInt($("#project tr:last").text());
        num+=1;
            $("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea name='pro_"+num+"' cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
                });
```

The 2nd page is the important page where all data from 1st page display on it:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_1"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_2"]; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td><?php echo $_POST["pro_3"];?></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is that the data of appended row didn't show on 2nd page.How to make it?
The output as below:

[image]

Comment: The add button should be outside of the table, also it may be easier to do something like this `$("#project").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea name='pro[]' cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");` then you can deal with the posted form in php as an array by `$_POST["pro"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you want to restructure your html into something like this.

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><textarea name="pro[]" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td><textarea name="pro[]" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td><textarea name="pro[]" cols="100" rows="2"></textarea></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr><td colspan='2'><input id="addbtn" type="button" name="addbtn" value="ADD"></td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Then update your javascript into something like this

```
$("#addbtn").click(function(){
    var num=$("#project tbody tr").length +1;
    $("#project tbody").append("<tr><td>"+num+"</td><td><textarea name='pro[]' cols='100' rows='2'></textarea></td></tr>");
}());
```

and finally on the php side you should be able to do this:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
    <?php foreach($_POST["pro"] as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key+1; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: try a `print_r` or `var_dump` on the `$_POST` array on the php side to make sure I didn't go full retard.

Answer (score 2):

On the second page do something like this:

```
<table width="600px" id="project">
    <?php foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: did you mean change all for my 2nd page?

Comment: If the second page contains only the code You have provided in the question, then yes, change it to what I have posted... If You have some other code, change only the appropriate HTML part...